# Open Graph Map layout

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, geolocation, facebook-opengraph

I succesfully posted an action to open graph with the 'Item' attachment layout. However I also want to post a action with the 'Map' attachment layout. My iOS app has an array with coordinates which form a route on a map.
I looked everywhere but just cant find a good tutorial which explains how to achieve this. Does someone know how to post a action to the open graph with a route preview on the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are creating your Open Graph custom Objects, you need to define a property of that Object as a GeoPoint and then set 'Is Array', like this:

[image: https://developers.facebook.com/attachment/object_geopoint.png/]

If you include this information, there should be a Map style newsfeed post automatically created when the action is published. You should also set up a Map style Aggregation. There is more [info on this here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-objects/#geopoint).

You can see an example of how this sort of complex route is created by looking at an example, here is one from an Endomondo workout:
http://pastebin.com/VEW2GU0t

Comment: so i basically send my array with lat and longitude to my webserver? Can you give me an example of the php file on my server where the data is retrieved from the meta tags. Something like this?

<meta property="vaarapp:latitude"  content="<?php echo strip_tags($_REQUEST['vaarapp:latitude']);?>">
      <meta property="vaarapp:longitude" content="<?php echo strip_tags($_REQUEST['vaarapp:longitude']);?>">

The example image of the map aggregation has highlighted point: route.location and route: route.track

What are these variables and where did they get defined?

Comment: Are the variables route.distance, route.time and route.speed custom properties?

Comment: Yes, they are custom properties. I have updated the end of my post with a link to example HTML that you can work off of.

Comment: I succesfully posten a action with map and location!

But how do I let facebook know that i have a route (array of locations)

Comment: If you follow all my instructions, you should be able to do this.

Comment: yep! didnt see your new post.

Comment: Still got 1 question. I edited my php so it would accept lat/long and altitude.
The problem is that Facebook debugger shows the same values for my lat/long and alt which is an array of 5 (always showing the last inserted value). I think this is because im overwriting the previous values.

<meta property="vaarapp:route:latitude"      content="<?php echo strip_tags($_REQUEST['vaarapp:route:latitude']);?>" >
      <meta property="vaarapp:route:longitude"  content="<?php echo strip_tags($_REQUEST['vaarapp:route:longitude']);?>">
      <meta property="vaarapp:route:altitude"   content="42">

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with PHP as I'm not very familiar with it, but it would seem to me that you'd need to have all that within a for loop?

Comment: @MatthewJohnston Can i implement all map check-ins in on one map using open graph?.

Comment: Hey, @Mark Molina can you tell me how did you attach the user's location within your iOS app? I've tried like this, but didn't work: NSMutableDictionary <FBOpenGraphObject> *object = [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPost]; [object setObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:47.50385],@"latitude",[NSNumber numberWithDouble:19.05567],@"longitude", nil] forKey:@"location"];

Comment: You're using the new FB SDK (3.6 or higher) right? I haven't been using that so I don't really know how you do that.
Im still using the old SDK and sending a location is a simple as sending a string with the name of the variable declared in the facebook open graph. Like this NSString *format =  @"%@:location:latitude=%f&"
    @"%@:location:longitude=%f&";