# How to correctly configure an Open Graph story with map attachment?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

In a test app I've set up an object (race) and an action (run). I'm now trying to set up a story that combines both of these.

Ideally the race object references a place on my app. But I've been experimenting with many configurations trying to get this to work — none successfully.

In the 'edit attachment' popup is a field 'highlighted points'. I believe this should provide a dropdown list of selectable options? It currently is not, and if I type free text into this field, it is not saved.

What am I doing wrong?

The `race` page on my app includes the following:

And the course pages include

>>>' />
>>' %> />

On Facebook, course is configured as a Place, race has the course property assigned. But I am unable to select `race.course:location` in the map popup.

I have also tried various configurations, including defining the lat/lon explicitly on the race page and defining appropriate properties on FB.

I am still unable to select the `highlighted points` value.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the answer at

- [Open Graph Map layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13292346/open-graph-map-layout)

This should be able to guide you.

Also

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/place/#properties

Comment: thanks. I'm passing a single point rather than route/array. The url debugger correctly parses all meta tags on the course page, and identified the geo coords. but the attachments popup is still not letting me select a `highlighted points` value.